# Mongoose `findOneAndUpdate` callback does not pass an updated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have separated my Mongoose code in `model.js` file, while Express code for handling http requests is in `app.js`. I'm just practising creating APIs and testing them on Postman, for an imaginary wiki article site. The issue is with `findOneAndUpdate` api. It is changing the database document as expected, however, the supposed updated document passed to the callback of the `findOneAndUpdate` api, is only the original document (before modification), not the newly update document. I console logged it just to confirm that. It would be ideal to pass the newly updated document in the callback so that in case I need to send the newly updated document as a response in a JSON, just to show confirmation of change.
I have shared my code below.
(Note: for the sake of brevity, I've only included the code in question, i.e. `app.put('/articles/:articleTitle' ....` from `app.js`, and the static method it calls from `model.js` - `updateReplaceArticleInDB`).

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const model = require('./model');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.put('/articles/:articleTitle', async (req, res) => {
    const articleTitle = req.params.articleTitle;
    const newArticleTitle = req.body.title;
    const newArticleContent = req.body.content;
    try {
        const response = await model.DBUtility.updateReplaceArticleInDB(articleTitle, newArticleTitle, newArticleContent);
        res.json({message: 'Successfully overwritten article', updatedArticle: response, app: 'wiki-api'});
    } catch (err) {
        res.json({message: err, app: 'wiki-api'});
    }
});

const port = 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

`model.js`

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

//connect to DB
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/wikiDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true, useFindAndModify: false }, 
(err) => {
    try {
        console.log(`Server connected successfully to MongoDB`);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});

const articleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: String,
    content: String
});

const Article = mongoose.model('Article', articleSchema);

class DBUtility {

static updateReplaceArticleInDB(articleTitle, newArticleTitle, newArticleContent) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            Article.findOneAndUpdate(
                {title: articleTitle}, 
                {$set: {title: newArticleTitle, content: newArticleContent}}, (err, updatedArticle) => {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    console.log(`updatedArticle: ${updatedArticle}`);
                    resolve(updatedArticle);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}

exports.DBUtility = DBUtility;
```

I have 5 articles (5 documents) in my Database:

```
{
    "_id" : "5c139771d79ac8eac11e754a",
    "title" : "API",
    "content" : "API stands for Application Programming Interface. It is a set of subroutine definitions, communication protocols, and tools for building software. In general terms, it is a set of clearly defined methods of communication among various components. A good API makes it easier to develop a computer program by providing all the building blocks, which are then put together by the programmer."
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : "5c1398aad79ac8eac11e7561",
    "title" : "Bootstrap",
    "content" : "This is a framework developed by Twitter that contains pre-made front-end templates for web design"
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : "5c1398ecd79ac8eac11e7567",
    "title" : "DOM",
    "content" : "The Document Object Model is like an API for interacting with our HTML"
}

/* 4 */
{
    "_id" : "5ea2c188fa57aa1b6453eda5",
    "title" : "Node JS",
    "content" : "Node.js is an open-source, cross-platform, JavaScript runtime environment that executes JavaScript code outside of a web browser. Node.js lets developers use JavaScript to write command line tools and for server-side scripting—running scripts server-side to produce dynamic web page content before the page is sent to the user's web browser. Consequently, Node.js represents a \"JavaScript everywhere\" paradigm,[6] unifying web-application development around a single programming language, rather than different languages for server- and client-side scripts.",
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 5 */
{
    "_id" : "5ea2d5304e19b11e0013a86a",
    "title" : "Bootstrap",
    "content" : "Bootstrap is an open source
toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and JS. Quickly prototype your ideas or build your entire app with our Sass variables and mixins, rins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt components, and powerful plugins
built on jQuery.",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The objective is to change the last document `"title" : "Bootstrap"` to `"title" : "EJS"` with `"content" : "EJS is a simple templating language ..."`.

However, when I make the http request on Postman, the returned document, that's supposed to be the newly updated one, is not. It's showing as the original old one (i.e. `"title": "Bootstrap"` instead of `"title": "EJS"`):

[image]

In terminal, the console logged `updatedArtilce` object passed to the callback of the `updateReplaceArticleInDB` api is also showing the old article `title: Bootstrap`, not the updated `EJS`:

```
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
Server started on port 3000
Server connected successfully to MongoDB
updatedArticle: {
  _id: 5ea2d5304e19b11e0013a86a,
  title: 'Bootstrap',
  content: 'Bootstrap is an open source
toolkit for developing with HTML, CSS, and JS. Quickly prototype your ideas or build your entire app with our Sass variables and mixins, rins, responsive grid system, extensive prebuilt components, and powerful plugins
built on jQuery.'
}
```

But the database does change the document successfully. It's just the Mongoose API is passing the old document in its callback rather than the new updated one.

[image]

Comment: add `{new: true}` as part of the findOneAndUpdate query

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/findoneandupdate.html), in order to get the updated document as result of a `findOneAndUpdate` function call, you need to pass `returnOriginal: false` or `new: true` as parameters of the option field. Here's an example:

```js
const filter = { name: 'Jean-Luc Picard' };
const update = { age: 59 };

// `doc` is the document after `update` was applied because of `returnOriginal: true`
const doc = await Character.findOneAndUpdate(filter, update, {
  returnOriginal: false
});

doc.name; // 'Jean-Luc Picard'
doc.age; // 59
```

Comment: Great. Thank you. I did go over this part of the documentation numerous times, but because of the format of the code, which assigns the the result to a constant, where I wanted to have a callback function instead to suite my code, I looked for examples elsewhere and forgot about the `new:true` option arg. Many thanks again.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Comment: I have no clue why but `new: true` used to work. However, it does not anymore. Good thing is that `returnOriginal: false` works! Thank you so much mate